# Pop up element outside of main browser window

Tags: javascript, macos, electron

I've been trying to build a macOS app with electron and I would like to add an element that is not confined to the main browser window; i.e. it hangs off the page.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:
[image: Skype Example]

Can someone give me some guidance here? Is this another browser window being rendered or is it kind of like a [sheet](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Concepts/AboutSheets.html)?

This feels like such a silly question but I've poked around in the electron API and the internet and I'm just not sure what I'm looking for.

If anyone could give me some insight, that would be wonderful. Thank you.

Comment: I think you mean a modal popup or dialog... http://stackoverflow.com/tags/modal-dialog/info

Comment: > These dialogs appear above all other content, blocking application flow until user input is received.

Comment: Whoops, hit save too early. It says: "These dialogs appear above all other content, blocking application flow until user input is received." If that's the case, then I don't think this is either.

Comment: then it's just a huge styled tooltip ;)  http://stackoverflow.com/tags/tooltip/info

Comment: ah now I see.. the white areas in your example are the browser and the popup.. and the mountain scene is the OS background.. correct?

Comment: Yes! I am sorry - I should've made that more clear. It definitely looks like a huge styled tooltip! But I need it to be able to hang outside of the browser window, and I'm not even sure if CSS could accomplish that.

Comment: actually I didn't pay enough attention.. anyway, I've never seen this on windows and I don't use a mac. Sorry I can't help you, but I added osx tag for the specialists to see ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After poking around some more on my computer, I found that this style of pop up is a 'pop over' window, similarly used for the tray apps on Mac.

I do not think this can be recreated natively in electron, HOWEVER, I have found that if you make a transparent frameless window (essentially invisible), you can markup some HTML with CSS in that window to give it the appearance similar to that of a popover.